# For loop from app.py to html returns unknown

Tags: python, for-loop, flask

I have some lists in my app.py and I am trying to display them in html, here is what I am doing:

```py
search = response.json()
book_id = []
titles = []
authors = []
thumbnails = []
for itm in search['items']:
    book_id.append(itm['id'])
    titles.append(itm['volumeInfo']['title'])
    authors.append(itm['volumeInfo']['authors'])
    thumbnails.append(itm['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'])
return render_template("search.html", search={
    "book_id": book_id,
    "title": titles,
    "author": authors,
    "thumbnail": thumbnails
})
```

```html
{% for i in search %}
<figure>
  <a href="/add/{{ search.book_id[i] }}" class="dropdown">ADICIONAR</a>
  <a><img src="{{ search.thumbnail[i] }}"></a>
  <figcaption>{{ search.title[i] }}</figcaption>
  <figcaption>{{ search.author[i] }}</figcaption>
</figure>
{% endfor %}
```

Html returns me nothing, and inside the `img src` it shows **unknown**. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you want to call it in html, I believe you need a list of dictionaries. I would do it as follows:

```py
search = response.json()
seek = search['items']
infobooks = []
for i in range(len(seek)):
    infobooks.append({"book_id": seek[i]['id'],
                      "thumbnail": seek[i]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'],
                      "title": seek[i]['volumeInfo']['title'],
                      "authors": seek[i]['volumeInfo']['authors']
    })
```

```html
{% for infobook in infobooks %}
<figure>
  <a href="/add/{{ infobook['book_id'] }}" class="dropdown">ADICIONAR</a>
  <a><img src="{{ infobook['thumbnail'] }}"></a>
  <figcaption>{{ infobook['title'] }}</figcaption>
  <figcaption>{{ infobook['authors'] }}</figcaption>
</figure>
{% endfor %}
```

Notice that I created a list called `infobooks` and that list receives the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

When you render your template, `search` is a dict, so when you loop over it you'll get its keys (`"book_id"`, `"title"`, `"author"`,  and `"thumbnail"`), which aren't useful as indexes into those lists.

You probably want to loop over the four lists separately, like `{% for i in search['book_id'] %}`

Comment: Isn't it possible to create a unique list with these four lists? I am trying to do, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Use the zip function to return a n-tuple of all the lists in the search dict and then iterate over that.

```py
{% for book_id, thumbnail, title, author in zip(search.book_id, search.thumbnail, search.title, search.author) %}
<figure>
  <a href="/add/{{ book_id }}" class="dropdown">ADICIONAR</a>
  <a><img src="{{ thumbnail }}"></a>
  <figcaption>{{ title }}</figcaption>
  <figcaption>{{ author }}</figcaption>
</figure>
{% endfor %}
```

Also remember to make zip function available as a template global

```py
@app.template_global(name="zip")
def t_zip(*iterable):
    return zip(*iterable)
```